# Nextra theme styles are overriding my component library's styles which uses tailwind css

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, nextra

I am using Nextra to write documentation for my ui library.

When I import my component in a .mdx file the theme styling of nextra is overriding my components original tailwind styling.

Nextra has a styles.css file in nextra-theme-docs which has a style for buttons

```
button,
[type=button],
[type=reset],
[type=submit] {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
}
```

This makes my imported buttons from my component transparent.

Note: When I create a page named `test.js` in pages folder the buttons style are rendered properly.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Install nextra and create a page called `button.mdx` in pages folder and also create a `_app.js` file in pages folder
2. Install my library `npm i dashboard-components-library` (it is still under development)
3. Install tailwind css following [this](https://nextra.site/docs/guide/advanced/tailwind-css) guide
4. Create a globals.css file in and add this tailwind css to it from [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kAvI7LyWoi4LKUUsegmU1bTydmzc_7vc/view) file and import this file in the _app.js file
5. Now add this code to your `button.mdx` file

```
# Getting Started
 
For existing or new project add the dashboard-components-library using the NPM package manager.

import { Button } from "dashboard-components-library";

<Button text="Primary Button Type" buttonType="Primary"></Button>
```

6. Run in dev mode

Comment: Maybe it is because you forgot to add a custom layout. nextra('./components/layout.js') with you next.config.js ?

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Please check out this repository with an implemented custom theme instead of me elaborating on next.config.js. https://github.com/jaredpalmer/nextra-blank-custom-theme/blob/main/next.config.js

Comment: But I am not using a custom theme. I am using the nextra-docs-theme